# Using command based docker image in .NetCore Api

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I am working on a .net core API which is running in a docker container. I want to use another docker image named subfinder (https://github.com/projectdiscovery/subfinder) to get the required data.
"subfinder" is not an API and needs to be called like below

```
docker run -it projectdiscovery/subfinder -v -d freelancer.com
```

I can use ProcessStartInfo in c# to run the image each time but it creates a new container each time I execute the above command. For each query, creating a new container may not be a good way. I also need to manage multiple executions at a time.

Is there any better way to use this docker image from c# code and solve it?

Comment: Why launch subfinder as a docker container if you can install it in your docker image alongside with your app?

Comment: @Lesiak: I thought of keeping the API image separate as different setups can use a different subdomain puller. But I should try what u suggested as well. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @Lesiak I didn't find any better way to specify the software to install in dockerfile. a hack would be to install it in a container and commit it as an image. It would be great if you can point me to something similar